# How to simulate survival times using true base line hazard function

Tags: r, survival, simulation

I want to simulate survival times from the model

$\lambda(t|X_1,X_2) = \lambda_0(t) \exp(\gamma_1X_1+\gamma_2X_2)$

where covariates are given by $X_1\sim$Binomial(1,0.5), $X_2\sim$Uniform(0,1), the true parameter values are

$\gamma_1=-0.5$, $\gamma_2=1.5$ and the true baseline hazard function is as follows

$ \lambda_0(t)=  \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      \exp(-0.3t); & 0<t\leq 1 \\
      \exp(-0.3); & 1<t\leq2.5 \\
      \exp(0.3(t-3.5)); & t>2.5
\end{array} 
\right. $

The censoring time is from the exponential distribution with mean 2.5.

For a simple baseline hazard function(e.g. $\lambda_0(t)=\lambda$), i used the following algorithm to generate survival times

$$T=H_0^-\{-\log(u) \times \exp(\gamma_1X_1+\gamma_2X_2)\}
=\lambda^-\{-\log(u) \times \exp(\gamma_1X_1+\gamma_2X_2))\}$$

where $u\sim$Uniform(0,1). The R codes are as follows

```
gamma <- c(-0.5, 1.5)
X1 <- rbinom(n=200,size=1,prob=.5)
X2 <- round(runif(n=200,0,1),2)
time <- (1/.3)*(-log(runif(200))/exp(gamma[1]*X1+gamma[2]*X2))
cen <- rexp(200,rate=1/2.5)
event <- as.numeric(time <= cen)
```

But i'm struggling to generate for the piecewise baseline hazard function that i mentioned above. Would anyone please help me to generate survival times for the above settings using R.

Comment: Rainer Walke has published a paper on ["Example for a Piecewise Constant Hazard Data Simulation in R"](http://www.demogr.mpg.de/papers/technicalreports/tr-2010-003.pdf). Might be usful.

Comment: I was unaware of this question and replied to a [very similar one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/302320)

Comment: You may find [this article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22763916) interesting - particularly section (3.1). You might be able to work on from Appendix A to more than one change point.

Answer (score 3):

First: you can sample directly from any survival function, $S(t)$ which shows the time-dependent probability of living to that time or longer. The way to do this is by generating uniform RVs $u$ as quantiles and finding $S^{-1}(u)$. This can be done analytically, or below I have an example of how to do it numerically with a pseudocontinuous or discrete time using `colSums(outer(x,y,'<'))` which beats `quantile` by many flops.

Second: the survival function is related to the hazard via: $S(t) = exp(-\Lambda(t))$ where $\Lambda(t) = \int_{0}^t \lambda(s) ds$ is called the cumulative hazard function.

So for simplicity let's sample just from the baseline hazard function, omitting any influence of covariates. As a note, the influence of covariates can be added back by generating survival curves for *each* individual in the sample by multiplying the hazard function by their exponentiated linear predictor. The cumulative hazard *could* be found analytically, but a numerical approach with a range of possible failure times is given by:

```
tdom <- seq(0, 5, by=0.01)
haz <- rep(0, length(tdom))
haz[tdom <= 1] <- exp(-0.3*tdom[tdom <= 1])
haz[tdom > 1 & tdom <= 2.5] <- exp(-0.3)
haz[tdom > 2.5] <- exp(0.3*(tdom[tdom > 2.5] - 3.5))
cumhaz <- cumsum(haz*0.01)
Surv <- exp(-cumhaz)
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
plot(tdom, haz, type='l', xlab='Time domain', ylab='Hazard')
plot(tdom, cumhaz, type='l', xlab='Time domain', ylab='Cumulative hazard')
plot(tdom, Surv, type='l', xlab='Time domain', ylab='Survival)

# generate 100 random samples:
u <- runif(100)
failtimes <- tdom[colSums(outer(Surv, u, `>`))]

dev.off()
library(survival)
plot(survfit(Surv(failtimes)~1))
```

Gives:

[image]
[image]